# react-native run-android error 500

Tags: android, react-native

I get successfull build, but react native saerches my root component in wrong location. 
My project is in `C://Projects/MobileApp` and I go there and run: `react-native-run-android`. It build successfully, but I get this error:
The development server returned response error code 500

```
Unable to resolve module build from C://Projects/MobileApp/index.android.js

Directory `C://Projects/MobileApp/build` does not exist.
```

This is true, but why is not searching it inside android folder where it exists:

`C://Projects/MobileApp/android/build` exists.

```
BTW, this is how I call my root component 
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { MyApp} from './build';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're importing from C://Projects/MobileApp/build here :

```
import { MyApp} from './build';
```

Don't put react-native .js files in android or ios folders, these folders are only for native android/ios code, i suggest creating a folder named `app` or `src` to put your react-native app code in.

You can write your MyApp component in `C://Projects/MobileApp/src/index.js` then import it in `C://Projects/MobileApp/index.android.js` by :

```
import { MyApp } from './src';
```

`run-android` command reads `index.android.js`

`run-ios` command reads `index.ios.js`